# Issue with uploading image to SAP OData Service - Put Method

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

I have implemented SAPUI5 signature pad and sending image(signature content) to SAP. My issue is passing signature pad image data to SAP using OData.request Put method.

**Step 1:**
I am able to get signature pad image data(content) and attached is copy of content looks like

"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBD/wAARCABkAlgDASIAAhEBAxEB

**Step 2:**
Sending Image data to SAP using OData.request put method.
In SAP /IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~UPDATE_STREAM class method I am only receiving IS_MEDIA_RESOURCE-mime_type I am not able to get
IS_MEDIA_RESOURCE-value. Below is my OData call logic:

```js
var oModel = this.getView().getModel();

oModel.setUseBatch(false);

​

var oData = {};

oData.Belnr = "4567891238";

oData.DocType = "ZLIEF";

oData.Role = "LKW";

​

var dataURL = this.byId("pressDialog").getContent()[2].getItems()[1]._getCanvasAsPicture("image/jpeg");

var base64string = dataURL.split(",")[1];

var serviceUrl = "/DigitalSignatureSet?(Belnr='" + oData.Belnr + "',DocType='" + oData.DocType + "',Role='" + oData.Role +

  "')/$value";

​

oModel.update(serviceUrl, oData, {

  method: "PUT",

  headers: {

    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",

    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",

    "DataServiceVersion": "2.0",

    "X-CSRF-Token": this.getView().getModel().getSecurityToken()

  },

  data: base64string

});

oModel.submitChanges(mParameters);
```

Regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [thread](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12435771/how-to-properly-implement-the-method-createstream-.html). It gives a pretty good explanation of what you need to do to upload an image by means of a data stream in Sap Netweaver Gateway.

Cheers,
SePo